# Effect of 5V on 3.3V GPIO

Tags: microcontroller

I am using a shield on top of a board with headers. One of the headers of the shield needs 5V but it also makes a connection to a 3.3V GPIO pin.

I am ok if that input is damaged since I am not going use it. Would applying  5V on 3.3V pin have an impact on  the operation of a microcontroller?  I am using an STM32F302R8 Nucleo board.

Comment: As Elliot said. applying 5V to a pin is not guaranteed to exclusively damage it, you can damage other things in the MCU and in the board (i.e. MCU has internal diodes which will possibly make the whole 3.3V rail go to 5V). That said, accourding to STM website, STM32F302R8 has: Up to 51 fast I/O ports, all mappable on external interrupt vectors, several 5 V-tolerant

Comment: So you should probably read the manual to see if the pins you want to apply 5V to are already 5V tolerant or not. It might not be a problem to begin with..

Comment: Yes I already had check before I asked. The pin I talk about is TTa only 3.3V tolerant. So I probably break that header pin to remove the connection to the uC input.

Comment: So did you check if the module outputs 5V or 3.3V?

Comment: Module does not output anything. It is powered through Nucelo. It gets 5V power from Nucelo's +5V pin which comes from Nucelo's E5V pin. I supply logic  5V externally to one of the module's pin. I use an Arduino shiled between the Nucleo and the module. I checked all the pins and power levels. The only problem as in the question, the 5V input pin of the module is also connected to Nucleo's unused GPIO pin which is 3.3V tolerant. I cannot change it since its how the shield routes it. So I think I will break that leg of the header.

Comment: I have two pins in same situation PB6 and PB10. PB6 is FTf and PB10 is TT type. So PB10 is 3.3V tolerant only. https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f302k6.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is twofold.

You don't say what shield it is, but it is possible that the shield uses 5V supply, and has onboard 3.3V regulation, so it might use 3.3V IO. You need to check if the shield IO is 5V or 3.3V.

You also don't say which specfic IO pin you are going to use on STM32F302R8. It has pins that are 5V tolerant, and it has pins that are not 5V tolerant. Feeding a 5V signal to a non-5V tolerant pin will damage it.

So it will either just work or be damaged depending on what IO voltage the shield uses and whether a 5V tolerant pin is used.

EDIT: So it is confirmed it is a 3.3V only pin. But not confirmed if the device actually outputs 5V to 3.3V pin.

The MCU might get damaged in any way, or if the current is limited, the IO pin voltage get clamped to about 3.6V as internal protection diode starts to conduct current from IO pin to 3.3V MCU supply. So it depends on how strong output the device has.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, applying 5V to an input pin rated at 3.3V can damage the device in unpredictable ways. It may not be just one pin that is damaged. Such a connection may also cause the 5V signal to be unable to reach a valid logic '1' level. Just don't do it.